# Acumatica REST API from Generic query returns only first record

Tags: acumatica, rest

I extended the Default webservice endpoint and created an endpoint for a generic query.  It runs fine but only returns the first record of the generic inquiry in string budgetitems.  There are about 100 recs when I do "view inquiry" manually in Acumatica.   When creating the endpoint I did create a detail object for results.  I can't see why it is not returning more than the first record.

Any help would be appreciated.  See code below:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

  namespace AcmBudTrxToAzure
  {
      class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        RestService rs = new RestService("https://acmsite.acumatica.com");           

        string parameters = "";
       
        string json2 = "{\"implicit:array:implicit:object\": [{\"\" : { } } ] }";
        
        string budgetitems = rs.Put("GLBudTrx", parameters, json2);

        Console.WriteLine("got here");

        Console.Write("Press  to exit... ");
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            //run loop until Enter is press
        }

    }

    public class RestService : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public readonly string _acumaticaBaseUrl;

        public RestService(
        string acumaticaBaseUrl)
        {
            _acumaticaBaseUrl = acumaticaBaseUrl;
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(
            new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseCookies = true,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
            })
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(acumaticaBaseUrl +
                  "/entity/auth/login"),
                DefaultRequestHeaders =
                {
                    Accept = { MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json")}
                }
            };
            //Log in to Acumatica ERP
            
            clsUser Usr = new clsUser();
            string nm = Usr.clsUserInfo.name;
            string pw = Usr.clsUserInfo.password;
            string cmp = Usr.clsUserInfo.company;
            string br = Usr.clsUserInfo.branch;
            string lc = Usr.clsUserInfo.locale;
            //var usrInfo = Usr.clsUserInfo;
            var str = new StringContent(
            new JavaScriptSerializer()
            .Serialize(
               new
               {
                   name = nm,
                   password = pw,
                   company = cmp,
                   branch = br,
                   locale = lc
               }),
               Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(
               acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/login",
                str).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            _httpClient.PostAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/logout",
                new ByteArrayContent(new byte[0])).Wait();
            _httpClient.Dispose();
        }

        public string Get(string entityName, string parameters)
        {
            var res = _httpClient.GetAsync(
            _acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/acmsiteEndpoint/20.200.001/"
            + entityName + "?" + parameters).Result
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        }

        public string Put(string entityName, string parameters, string entity)
        {

            var res = _httpClient
            .PutAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/acmsiteEndpoint/20.200.001/" +
                               entityName + "?$expand=Results" ,
            new StringContent(entity, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            .Result
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.  It was not in the code.  I regenerated the detail object on the Acumatica endpoint and it now works.  Not sure if it matters but I originally I named the detail object "results" and when I regenerated it I changed it to something else.